# jquery ui change function name from slider to slider1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

I am using jquery ui range slider
http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
```

if i use this cod eon my test page then it works fine

but when i am going to use this in magento there is Error cause i am using also anothe slider
now i want to change the name in `jquery-ui.js` as `slider1` so i can use this slider as

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider1({
               // ui code
    });

  });
```

so where i have to make change

Comment: you can use multiple sliders on the same page! Try to verify if there is the same ID for previous sliders.. You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID!

Comment: Why would you want to change the name to `slider1`?

Comment: i am also using another ranhe slider it has the same name so there is Error

Comment: @MateiMihai yes i know that i have checked it

Answer (score 1):

if some other had the same problem, i had to add the next line after jquery ui and before jquery mobile

```
$.fn.uislider = $.fn.slider;
```

the code example will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>  
    // rename to avoid conflict with jquery mobile
    $.fn.uislider = $.fn.slider;
  </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).uislider();
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new property in the jQuery object's prototype *after* including jQuery UI and *before* including the module that introduces the conflicting `slider()` method:

```
$.fn.slider1 = $.fn.slider;
```

Note, however, that this will only rename the bridge method attached to the prototype. The widget will still be named `$.ui.slider` under the hood.